# Does it hold/can you prove that if $\frac{1}{x} + x$ is an integer, then $x = 1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to show that if $\frac{1}{x} + x$ is an integer, then $x = 1$, where $x$ is a positive integer. Not sure where to begin

Comment: If $x$ is positive then  $x<x+\frac 1x <x+1$.

Comment: @lulu: I think you mean $x<x+\frac1x\le x+1.$

Comment: @CameronBuie  True.  Well, I ought to have said "if $x>1$ then $x<x+\frac 1x<x+1$"

Comment: This question has significantly changed from the original posting.  Now, there is no context for the question and the answers do no make sense.  I suggest a rollback.  The original question was to prove that if $\frac{1}{x}+x$ is an integer, then $x=1$ (supposing, unstated, that $x$ is a positive integer).

Comment: Do not deface your questions.

Comment: @MichaelBurr In such situations, you can roll back yourself (click on the "edited some time ago" link to get to the revisions, and then click the "rollback" link at the revision you want to roll back to).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the suggestion.  I wanted to give the OP a chance to roll it back or continue a thought if the post occurred by accident.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use $n$ instead of $x$, as this is how positive integers are typically denoted.

You want to prove the statement $\frac1n+n\in\mathbb{N} \implies n=1$.

Instead, prove the equivalent statement $n\neq1 \implies \frac1n+n\not\in\mathbb{N}$:

$n\neq1\implies$

$n>1\implies$

$\frac1n<1\implies$

$\frac1n\not\in\mathbb{N}\implies$

$\frac1n+n\not\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: You might want to refine "$\frac1n<1$" into "$0<\frac1n<1$".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\gt 1$. Then, $\frac1x\lt1$.

Since $x$ is an integer, if $x+\frac1x$ was an integer, then, $$x+\frac1x-x=\frac1x$$ would be an integer.

But $0\lt\frac1x\lt1$. Thus, as no integer lies between $0$ and $1$, $\frac1x$ cannot be an integer.

The only possibility left is $x=1$, which is easily verified.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, since $x$ is integer , for $x+\frac{1}{x}$ to be integer, $\frac{1}{x}$ should be integer , since $\text{integer}+\text{unknown} = \text{integer}$ $\implies$ $\text{unknown} = \text{integer}$, $\frac{1}{x}$ is integer only when $x$ divides $1$, which is when $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\frac{1}{x}-x=n$ for some integer $n$. Then $1=x(n-x)$. Hence $x\mid 1$. Since $x$ is a postive integer that divides 1, we conclude that $x=1$.